# Powershell Removing Leading Zero from File Name

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with Several files from the that look like:

> XXX_01_07_11_1.bat
>   XX_1_07_06_02.bat
>   XXXX_2_22_14_01_02.bat

Without a specific length.

I would like to rename all the files in the folder removing all the leading zeros.
for example XXX_01_07_11_1.bat will be renamed to XXX_1_7_11_1.bat .

I found some ways to do it in Bash but not with powershell.

Comment: `$x='XX_01_0007_006_00002.bat';While ( $x -match '_0' ) { $x = $x.Replace('_0', '_'); $x}`

Comment: Wouldnt that cause XX_0_01_02.bat to turn into XX__1_2.bat ? removing a 0 that i actually need?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the easiest way to use something like this to replace the leading zeros `-replace '(0)(\d)','$2'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `_0+(?=[1-9])` or `_0+(?=\d)` regex as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem . -File -Filter "*_0*.*" |
    ForEach-Object {
        Rename-Item $_.FullName $($_.Name -replace '_0+(?=\d)', '_') -WhatIf
    }
```

Remove the risk mitigation parameter `-WhatIf` as soon as debugged (or use `-WhatIf:$false` to suppress the automatic *WhatIf* behaviour that results when the value of the `$WhatIfPreference` variable is `1`, see also [`Get-Help about_Preference_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6)).

**Regex explanation:**

- `_` matches the character `_` *Low Line (underscore)* literally
- `0+` matches the character `0` literally

  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (*greedy*)
- `?=` Positive Lookahead. Assert that above `_0+` match is followed by

  - `[1-9]` a single character in the `[1-9]` list i.e. in the range between 1 (unicode 49) and 9 (unicode 57), or
  - `\d` a digit (equals to `[0-9]` list *but `[1-9]` effectively due to greedy ´0+´ above*).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
get-childitem "c:\temp" -file -filter "*.bat" | %{

$NewName=($_.Name -split '_' | %{if ($_ -eq '0') {'0'} else {$_.TrimStart('0')}}) -join '_'
Rename-Item $_.FullName $NewName

}
```

Comment: Don't make it too complicated, just replace `_0` with `_`. :)

Comment: with a file name like XXXX_2_22_14_001_02.bat (multiple 0 before _) your code doesnt work ;)

Comment: Nothing happens when i`m running this Script , 
@SystemError If you only replace _0 with _ , you might end up removing 0`s that are stand alone meaning 01_0_2_3 will change to 1__2_3 , instead of 1_0_2_3 .

Comment: check you PowerShell version, this script work. Have your modified the path (c:\temp)?

Comment: Although , it removed all 0`s , even its not a leading zero , meaning 
1_0_03  turns into 1__3 , instead of 1_0_3

Comment: I have modifed my script for keep 0 wich are alone ;)

Comment: Referring to the sample, I thought it's date time strings. Hmm... regex is much better for this question. BTW, how can I reply a specific comment or expert?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is replacing `_0` to `_`, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem _my_Path | ForEach-Object {
    $f_name = $_.FullName
    $name = $_.Name
    $new_name = $name -replace "_0","_"
    Rename-Item $f_name -NewName $new_name
}
```

Please have a try. :)

Comment: $f_name is a path , while $new_name is just a filename ,
When trying to preform Rename-Item you getting : 
"Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:5 char:5
+     Rename-Item $f_name -NewName $new_name
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Temp\Automation\Old:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand"

Comment: it removed all 0`s , even its not a leading zero , meaning 1_0_03 turns into 1__3 , instead of 1_0_3

Comment: Hmm, it's my fault, just rename the file and set `_0.+` as the source, I think it works.

Comment: _0.+ as source removes everything after the first _0 .. 

C:\Temp\Automation\Vf3RsuImageLE_30_0_2_253_1_5_30_01_2_253_1_5.bin --> C:\Temp\Automation\Vf3RsuImageLE_30_

Answer (score 1):

```
cd c:\temp

'X_01_00007_11_1.bat','X_1_07_06_02.bat','X_2_22_14_01_02.bat','X_000_0_07_06_02.bat'|% {
New-Item $_ -Force}

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File |ForEach-Object {
    $oldname=$_.Name
    $newname = $oldname -replace '_0+(?=\d)', '_'
    #or
    #$newname = $oldname -replace '_0+(\d)', '_$1'
    Rename-Item $oldname -NewName $newname 
}
```

目录: C:\temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_01_00007_11_1.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_1_07_06_02.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_2_22_14_01_02.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_000_0_07_06_02.bat

PS C:\temp> dir

目录: C:\temp

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_0_0_7_6_2.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_1_7_11_1.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_1_7_6_2.bat
-a----         2018/5/7     20:55              0 X_2_22_14_1_2.bat

Comment: OP says "I would like to rename all the files in the folder" so you're missing first part. It probably needs to begin with `dir` before you pipe it to replace.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: This is at heart similar to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50222776/45375), but demonstrates that you can pipe `Get-ChildItem` output *directly* to `Rename-Item`, which is both more concise and more efficient.</sup>

```
Get-ChildItem . -Filter *.bat |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=_)0+' } -WhatIf
```

Specify the desired target folder instead of `.`
`-WhatIf` *previews* the renaming; remove it to actually rename.

- You can pass a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to `Rename-Item -NewName`, which is evaluated for each input object (file), and in which `$_` refers to the file at hand.

  - Note that this works even though `-NewName` is a `[string]`-typed parameter. The ability to pass a script block instead - a *script-block parameter* is a powerful generic PowerShell feature that allows you to *calculate* the parameter value on a *per-input-object* basis via a script block - see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2338) for details.
- `-replace` performs regex-based string replacement and `'(?<=_)0+'` replaces any sequence of one or more (`+`) `0` chars., if preceded by (`?<=`) a `_` char.

  - `(?<=_)` is an instance of a (positive) *lookbehind assertion*, which means that while the `_` is *matched*, it won't be *captured*; that is, it doesn't become part of what is being *replaced*.
  - Since no replacement string is given, the zeros are effectively *removed*.